# Can't find how to use HttpContent

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I am trying to use `HttpContent`:

```
HttpContent myContent = HttpContent.Create(SOME_JSON);
```

...but I am not having any luck finding the DLL where it is defined.

First, I tried adding references to `Microsoft.Http` as well as `System.Net`, but neither is in the list. I also tried adding a reference to `System.Net.Http` but the `HttpContent` class is not available.

So, can anyone tell me where I can find the `HttpContent` class?

Answer (score 471):

Just use...

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(jObject.ToString());
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://www.sample.com/write", stringContent);
```

Or,

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://www.sample.com/write", stringContent);
```

Comment: Says the content parameter needs to be IHttpContent and not StringContent. When I cast it to the interface it's happy, though.

Comment: Ended up using HttpStringContent. I couldn't use the StringContent class because PostAsync (or PutAsync in my case) doesn't accept StringContent even if you cast it to a IHttpContent object.

Comment: StringContent works for me with PostAsync, but if you want or need to use HttpContent, you can do so like this:

HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonString);

Comment: I keep seeing this answer to what appears to be a similar problem to mine, however as I debug through both of my APIs, I get a PostAsync("path", StringContent) to fire but when it hits the other API I don't have a body to parse and use and on return I get a 500... I am at a loss as it appears I am doing it just like this. Only difference is that I don't serialize the object as it is already serialized when I receive it in the first API and it is a simple passthrough.

Comment: This should be the answer :/

Comment: @DanielV No, that should not be an answer to question '*Can't find how to use HttpContent*' without explaining anything.

Answer (score 172):

To take 6footunder's comment and turn it into an answer, `HttpContent` is abstract so you need to use one of the derived classes:

[image]

Comment: Looks like he used Visual Studio's "Class Diagram" feature (Right-click your project, Add Item, Class Diagram. Then you can go thru Solution Explorer and expand References to get diagrams of libraries you reference.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/working-with-class-diagrams-class-designer

Comment: @Chris, Please explain how you generated this class diagram for HttpContent...

Answer (score 128):

For JSON Post:

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://www.sample.com/write", stringContent);
```

Non-JSON:

```
var stringContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("field1", "value1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("field2", "value2"),
});
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://www.sample.com/write", stringContent);
```

https://blog.pedrofelix.org/2012/01/16/the-new-system-net-http-classes-message-content/

Comment: I'm trying to use your "non-json" example, how should I read the data on the receiving end?

Comment: var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Answer (score 6):

While the final version of HttpContent and the entire System.Net.Http namespace will come with .NET 4.5, you can use a .NET 4 version by adding the [Microsoft.Net.Http](http://nuget.org/Packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) package from NuGet

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the code is not using the System.Net.Http.HttpContent class, but instead Microsoft.Http.HttpContent.
Microsoft.Http was the WCF REST Starter Kit, which never made it out preview before being placed in the .NET Framework.
You can still find it here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644

I would not recommend basing new code on it.

Answer (score -2):

Just leaving the way using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` here.

Example:

```
var client = HttpClientFactory.Create();
var result = await client.PostAsync<ExampleClass>("http://www.sample.com/write", new ExampleClass(), new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```