# What purposes should I use class StringContent for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is [StringContent class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent) in System.Net.Http namespace. What purposes should I use class StringContent for?

Comment: You can read the methods.

Comment: Do not care about it. If you come across another type in the System.Net.Http namespace which uses the StringContent type, then you will also know what its purpose is....

Comment: see also [Can't find how to use HttpContent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21879362)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It provides HTTP content based on a string.

### Example:

Adding the content on HTTPResponseMessage Object

```
response.Content = new StringContent("Place response text here");
```

Comment: Could you give me example of using?

Comment: @oblomov: Provided an example

Comment: @SivaCharan what is its purpose?  When would one use this?

Comment: I guess StringContent does not support escape characters like \r\n. I am passing those characters in my string, but for some reason it fails @SivaCharan

Comment: @SivaCharan, I do retrieve the string client side? I m not able

Answer (score 29):

StringContent class creates a formatted text appropriate for the http server/client communication. After a client request, a server will respond with a `HttpResponseMessage`and that response will need a content, that can be created with the `StringContent` class.

Example:

```
 string csv = "content here";
 var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
 response.Content = new StringContent(csv, Encoding.UTF8, "text/csv");
 response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", 
                              "attachment; 
                              filename=yourname.csv");
 return response;
```

In this example, the server will respond with the content present on the `csv` variable.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever I want to send an object to web api server I use  StringContent to add format to HTTP content, for example to add Customer object as json to server:

```
 public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        String apiUrl = "Web api Address";
        HttpClient _client= new HttpClient();

        string JsonCustomer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonCustomer, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = _client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content).Result;

    }
```

Comment: It is best practice to not create a new HttpClient for every request :)

Comment: @Nora yeah httpfactory nowadays is so sexy and fun!

Answer (score 3):

Every response that is basically text encoded can be represented as `StringContent`.

Html reponse is text too (with proper content type set):

```
response.Content = new StringContent("<html><head>...</head><body>....</body></html>")
```

On the other side, if you download/upload file, that is binary content, so it cannot be represented by string.