# What is StringContent in C#?

Tags: c#, string, api, .net-core

What does StringContent mean in C# Net Core? When researching, I received this "Provides HTTP content based on a string." What does this mean in layman's term?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh138250(v%3Dvs.118)

Comment: A similar question is asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479177/what-purposes-should-i-use-class-stringcontent-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringContent is used for representing data that is text encoded and can be represented in a string easily. HTML is text encoded so the StringContent class is used for HTML often.

Something like binary would not be represented using the StringContent class.